# No-IP: I can not access computer port 80, redirected to router login page instead

Tags: wireless-networking, router, noip

I want to access my computer from outside the network. I'm using No-IP to get my computer static IP address. It works fine. When I'm accessing the host on port 80, it's not reaching my computer but just shows the router login page.

I think this issue occurs because *all* the devices connected use the same IP address when I'm accessing it via the router,

- **How could I have an unique public IP address on the network?**
- **How could I fix this issue?**

Comment: It is most likely because your router has "access management interface from WAN" enabled, and that supercedes the port forward.  What router is it?

Comment: As @Paul says, you've probably got your router's web management GUI enabled (for remote management of your router). You may be able to change this port to, say, 9090.

Comment: @Paul my router is HG532E Claro, I forgot to say I have Apache server running with xampp and ftp port open on my computer and I want to access those directories from outside, it seems like hosting

Comment: Have you got port 80 on the host you want to access forwarded to the router?  You can only have one host accessible at port 80 (or any port).  You will have to forward to different ports to access any other hosts, using something like `http://yourdomain.com:8080`.

Comment: At last, problem solved, Thanks, yes can not have same port with two targets, I changed port 80 to 8080 and for reaching to my computer, I thought with those changes It'd be solved, but my computer was refusing access, so firewall was blocking me, I did have to change some configurations of my firewall, And that's it

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I realized firewall was blocking connection, 
Just make sure you have your port listening and forwarded,
all will work fine.